# i have start to login with google using fast api i can find the error of internal server error

Tags: async-await

```
@app.get("/login/google")
async def login_google(request: Request):
    authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")
    request.session["oauth_state"] = state
    return RedirectResponse(authorization_url)

@app.get("/login/google/callback")
async def login_google_callback(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    state = request.session.pop("oauth_state", None)
    print(state)
    if not state:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid state")

    token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
    print("------------------------")

    await oauth.fetch_token(token_url, authorization_response=str(request.url), client_secret=config("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"))

    user_info = oauth.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo").json()
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.google_id == user_info["id"]).first()
    print(user)
    if not user:
        user = models.User(
            first_name=user_info["given_name"],
            last_name=user_info["family_name"],
            email=user_info["email"],
            google_id=user_info["id"]
        )
        db.add(user)
        db.commit()

    access_token = security.create_access_token(data={"sub": user.email})
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

I think error in this line:-await oauth.fetch_token(token_url, authorization_response=str(request.url), client_secret=config("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"))

{"access_token": vchbjncmdcsdccwecwekx, "token_type": "bearer"}